# Searching for a substring in C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, substring

This is something  for searching a substring In a 2d array 
    int search_left2right(char * matrix, char * word)
    {
    int i;

```
for (i = 0; i != ROW*COLUMN; ++i) {
int j = i;
char * w = word;

while (*w == matrix[j]) {
  if (!*++w)
    return i * 1000 + j;
  if (++j == ROW*COLUMN)
    j = 0;
}
}

return -1;
}
```

Can someone explain to me what these two lines do?  Espacially the if statement and can anyone make this code not use any pointers they mess up my code when I implement it.I want to make it o that `char * w = word;` this line would be unnecessary.Something like `while(word[something]=matrix[j]` but I cant make it work

```
 while (*w == matrix[j]) {
  if (!*++w)
```

Here is what it is doing

```
Enter the string to be searched in the puzzle:
SHOUT
position in the puzzle: 12
PUZZLE(MATRIX)
X  T  Z  M  Q  Y  K  C  E  C  F  H -->0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 
*S  H  O  U  T*  E  X  O  E  A  P  I -->12 13 14 ------------23
X  G  T  L  Q  B  E  L  T  N  F  K
A  I  R  I  D  Z  A  L  L  I  O  D
M  E  I  E  T  Y  S  E  H  R  T  I
A  W  B  R  N  E  T  C  W  O  H  X
N  O  U  I  R  U  Z  T  S  C  C  T
U  D  T  P  E  C  J  I  E  H  R  U
A  L  E  M  C  S  Y  O  N  I  U  R
L  V  *K  E  R  E  M*  N  I  P  H  E
E  A  N  B  U  R  E  J  O  N  C  Y
A  W  I  I  I  J  N  J  R  U  Y  F
D  W  T  N  T  H  E  N  P  J  Y  T
E  Q  L  Z  D  I  L  E  M  M  A  B
R  C  I  T  E  N  G  A  M  T  P  C
returns the index of the words first element
```

Comment: Do you know how pointer dereferencing works?  Understand dereferencing, and you'll understand how this code works.

Comment: I kind of do but Im asking for a way without it because I have to explain this to someone that doesnt know what a pointer is

Comment: Not possible.  Teach them how pointers work first.

Comment: Anyway, for what it's worth, `w[0]` is equivalent to `*w`, and `w = w + 1; w[0]` is equivalent to `*++w`

Comment: Shouldn't matrix be char* array or char**?

Comment: The function of this code is completely unclear to me, given that `matrix` is a one dimensional array of chars.

Comment: You changed your question completely with an edit.  I'm voting to close.  This isn't a tutorial site or a site substitute for doing proper research.

Comment: The content of the question has changed, resulting in making all of the comments, and answers thus far of no value.  If you need to get a review of the new function, the correct way to do that is to post a _new question_ , perhaps on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) asking about the functionality, or problems with new function.

Comment: Accidently changed it it should be back now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i != ROW*COLUMN; ++i) {//limit search to length of memory containing `word`
    int j = i;
    char * w = word;               //set pointer `w` equal to the beginning of `word`

    while (*w == matrix[j]) {      //while the value pointed to by the
                                   //current location of `w` is equal 
                                   //to the value *(matrix + j)  

        if (!*++w)                 // after incrementing `w` test that it is not `null` (end of `word`)
            return i * 1000 + j;   //return the value represented by the expression
        if (++j == ROW*COLUMN)     //after incrementing `j` test for equality with end of `word`
            j = 0;                 // reset `j` for another loop
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u so much. I understand . Could you look at the new function I posted it is without pointers tho

Comment: If `j` is reset, then it will be an infinite `while` loop because `!*++w` was, and so will, never be true. Hence the code eludes me completely.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - I do not know why this was written the way it was.  It seems purposefully obfuscated.

Answer (score 1):

In the code

```
while (*w == matrix[j]) {
   if (!*++w)
```

The `while` condition is using an ordinary dereference.  It reads as *"the character at the memory location pointed to by the memory address stored in w.* And then, that character is tested for equality against the element in the matrix array located at index `j`.

The `if` condition should be broken up into its respective operations.  There's too much going on there for someone not experienced in C to understand it:

```
w = w + 1; // or ++w.  Advances w to the next memory location.
if (*w == 0) // is the character at that location the null termination character?
```